# Serialization over Pipes

Tags: c++, serialization, stream, pipe, boost-serialization

I wrote several simulation programs in C++ and want to connect their outputs/inputs with pipes (best solution would probably be to use the C++ streams).

For this I would like to serialize some objects (for example the simulations output/input are tensors and matrices). How should I handle this problem? I searched around for some time for serialization + pipes on google but was not really able to find anything about this...

Any tips on a starting point? Is it easy for example to use the boost/serialization to exchange objects with pipes? Generally I would be pleased, if serialization is text-based (to avoid rounding errors I would send hex-values rather than decimal), so I could redirect the output streams into textfiles, split them up etc...  Also this way I could probably write my simulations in different programs...

Thx for all the answers!

Comment: Bad idea, surely you are using floating point values?  Redirecting requires converting them to text.  The text representation will introduce subtle rounding errors.  Use files instead so you can store the data in binary.  Saves you a lot of work too.

Comment: you're right.. I forgot to mention that I was thinking about hex values, rather than decimal...  that would avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check these libraries:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrift_(protocol)

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/

Comment: +1 on Google protocol buffers.  This would be especially useful if you ever decided to write a simulation in Java or Python.

Comment: thx.. i didn't know about these two libraries. Especially the Google Library lloks appealing to me. Thrift lacks a little bit ofdocumentation I think and also is probably somewhat of an overkill for my rather "simple" problem.

I think I will first try the google library, on the other hand I just realized using some kind of validation, maybe I would be best of trying it on my own, without any serialization. I'll post here, if that makes more sense...